# How can a leased line be securely shared between businesses?

Tags: firewall, security

The owner of a business site (in the UK) with about 10 independent business on it (of which I occupy one) is thinking of installing a leased line for shared use by those businesses.

He is asking what the safest/securest way is to enable the line to be shared between the businesses while at the same time keeping the businesses LANs separate with no communication between them?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not clear what the leased line would connect. Are there 2 sites with the same businesses running or both? Is it an Internet access?

Comment: Are you saying that you have a single site with 10 offices, and they are proposing using a single leased line to be shared by all 10 offices?

Comment: @JFL - sorry, not clear - it is one site, with 10 independent business.  All 10 businesses would share (for some definition of "share") the single leased line.

Comment: @user3623501 - see other comment above; 1 site; 10 independent businesses.

Comment: so this is actually a shared internet connection? Usually the term "leased line" refer to a (private, dedicated) line that connect two remote sites together.

Comment: @JFL yes, it will (hopefully) be a shared internet connection. I understand "usually" the term leased term refers to a private dedicated line, but not in this case - I'm using it to refer to a high bandwidth non-contended internet line.

Comment: As discussed, [leased line costs](https://www.leasedlineandmpls.co.uk) have come down dramatically and security is a high priority but I agree with the above. A great option is a Private VLAN

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers did help at the time, but things have moved on now, and BT will be providing FTTP which simplifies the options for the business drastically!

Leased lines, routers, firewalls, etc. will not be required!

Answer (score 2):

You want to share an ISP or Internet connection.

This can be achieved with a single 12 port layer 3 ethernet switch, provided the Internet handoff is Ethernet, otherwise you will need to front-end the switch with a router to terminate non-Ethernet links.  Then, each tenant requires a router or firewall device as the demarc to their network.

Have your ISP issue you /28, or 14 global IP addresses.  You might have to pay a little extra for this.  One of those addresses is assigned to the ISP gateway, and that leaves you 13 addresses to hand/assign to your tenants to apply to the outside interface of their routers/firewalls.

Thanks it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probarly need to implement VLANs on that building to separate different kinds of traffics, and also share the media. If by some reason you want to connect to another place, a L2VPN is what you need, to securely the traffic, avoiding interception and that stuff.

Answer (score 1):

If possible I would try and get a block of public IPv4 IPs big enough ( a /28 from your description) that each buisness could have their own IPv4 ip. I would also try to get a /48 of IPv6.

The router on the end of the leased line from the ISP would be acting as a simple router with no NAT or firewalling.

Behind that router each buisness could have their own NAT router/firewall which would be allocated a single IPv4 address and a /56 block of IPv6.

While this does involve more hardware than having one box manage everything it means that each buisness is in control of their own network and configuration of the shared router should be very much "set and forget".

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably not worded well. Why install a leased line if you don't want communications between sites?

You can put routers and/or firewalls on each end of a leased line, and you can put in rules/ACLs to limit the communications to/from certain hosts/servers/networks, etc.

**Edit:**

Any good firewall can block traffic between the businesses using the same leased line. Basically, you can separate the businesses by VLAN, and forbid traffic between the VLANs. Firewalls normally default to block everything, and then only allow what you specifically configure them to allow.

Comment: Modified question for clarity.  We don't want direct communication between businesses, but we all want the bandwidth to the outside world.

Comment: I kind of guess "routers and/or firewalls" would be involved - do you have any useful links/articles/providers etc.?   Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, product and resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive that by ususing VLAN with VACL or use protected ports (easiest option). 
Another options is Isolated PVLAN.